# React Native Border Width 6s Plus

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

So I have a really strange issue in React Native.

When I use 0.5 for borderWidth, it shows really thick lines up only on the iPhone 6s Plus simulator. I can correct it but by seeing when it is the 6s Plus dimension but don't get the 0.5 width I want.

Any ideas would be helpful on a way to get 0.5 to work.

```
halfTopBorder: {
  borderTopWidth: 0.5,
  borderColor: styleVariables.borderColor
},

//Changed to...

halfTopBorder: {
 borderTopWidth: styleVariables.windowHeight === 736 ? 1 : 0.5,
 borderColor: styleVariables.borderColor
},
```

Comment: Sometimes emulator line rendering is not exactly the same as what you get in real device. Try it in real device and see if it still happens.

Answer (score 10):

You want to use StyleSheet.hairlineWidth. It will give you a sharp line on all the devices :)